# npm install task from package.json on Ansible Playbook fails to work

Tags: ansible, devops

I'm want to add an Ansible task to perform `npm i` from `package.json` after `git pull`. The pull works successfully but npm i doesn't. I've tried two approaches:

1.

```
- name: Install Packages
  npm: 
    path: PATH_TO_PACKAGE.JSON_DIRECTORY
    state: latest
  environment:
    PATH: ENVIRONMENT_PATH
```

It throws the following error:
[image]

2.

```
- name: Install Packages
  shell: npm install --silent
  args:
    chdir: PATH_TO_PACKAGE.JSON_DIRECTORY
  register: npm
  environment:
    PATH: ENVIRONMENT_PATH
```

It throws the following error:
[image]

Seemed like the issue is occurring due to the warning messages that we encounter while executing `npm i` but we're encountering the issue even after adding the --silent flag.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks. Using images  is usually barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, visually impaired people cannot use their voice synthesizer, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed, it uses 1000x more data volume than the equivalent text. And above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks